# 2017: Trending our answered percentage ranking to 1st

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, statistics

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 100% (with rounding, at least), and our rank site-wide at 1st for answering, and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

At time of writing (Feb 3rd, 2017) we have:

- [72 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [59 questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [100%ish answer rate, which puts us at 9th overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

Comment: @pnuts Merged unanswered Qs?

Answer (score 11):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answered rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answered rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank   |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| June 22, 2017        |   102   |   81      |   100%    |  11th  |
| May 15, 2017         |   35    |   27      |   100%    |   5th  |
| May 14, 2017         |   38    |   33      |   100%    |   4th  |
| May 5, 2017          |   48    |   40      |   100%    |   5th  |
| May 3, 2017          |   38    |   33      |   100%    |   5th  |
| April 28th, 2017     |   32    |   25      |   100%    |   4th  |
| April 21st, 2017     |   37    |   30      |   100%    |   5th  |
| April 13th, 2017     |   17    |   16      |   100%    |   3rd  |
| April 10th, 2017     |   9     |   9       |   100%    |   3rd  |   
| April 8th, 2017      |   12    |   10      |   100%    |   4th  |
| April 7th, 2017      |   15    |   15      |   100%    |   4th  |
| April 6th, 2017      |   13    |   13      |   100%    |   4th  |
| April 5th, 2017      |   23    |   21      |   100%    |   4th  |
| April 4th, 2017      |   28    |   22      |   100%    |   5th  |
| April 3rd, 2017      |   27    |   23      |   100%    |   5th  |
| March 31st, 2017     |   34    |   31      |   100%    |   5th  |
| March 28th, 2017     |   35    |   34      |   100%    |   6th  |
| March 27th, 2017     |   35    |   34      |   100%    |   5th  |
| March 26th, 2017     |   39    |   38      |   100%    |   6th  |
| March 25th, 2017     |   38    |   36      |   100%    |   7th  |
| March 24th, 2017     |   40    |   37      |   100%    |   5th  |
| March 23rd, 2017     |   39    |   37      |   100%    |   5th  |
| March 22nd, 2017     |   46    |   41      |   100%    |   6th  |
| March 21st, 2017     |   55    |   46      |   100%    |   7th  |
| March 20th, 2017     |   52    |   48      |   100%    |   6th  |
| March 19th, 2017     |   61    |   54      |   100%    |   7th  |
| March 18th, 2017     |   64    |   57      |   100%    |   8th  |
| March 17th, 2017     |   69    |   63      |   100%    |   7th  |
| March 16th, 2017     |   77    |   70      |   100%    |   9th  |
| March 15th, 2017     |   84    |   76      |   100%    |  10th  |
| March 6th, 2017      |   69    |   62      |   100%    |   8th  |
| March 1st, 2017      |   62    |   54      |   100%    |   7th  |
| February 26th, 2017  |   59    |   47      |   100%    |   7th  |
| February 23rd, 2017  |   68    |   53      |   100%    |   7th  |
| February 21st, 2017  |   71    |   55      |   100%    |   9th  |
| February 14th, 2017  |   62    |   46      |   100%    |   9th  |
| February 12th, 2017  |   71    |   56      |   100%    |   8th  |
| February  8th, 2017  |   67    |   53      |   100%    |   8th  | 
| February  7th, 2017  |   77    |   60      |   100%    |  10th  | 
| February  4th, 2017  |   78    |   63      |   100%    |   8th  | 
| February  3rd, 2017  |   72    |   59      |   100%    |   9th  |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: We have a lot of answers with no upvotes in the list. Let's make an efforet to go through them and either vote to delete or upvote.

Comment: @JonathanReez or downvote*.  Some haven't been great :/ But yeah, reward those who have found answers for sure.