# 2018 Goal: Reduce unanswered - currently 15th (245 unanswered) across network

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

At time of writing (February 22nd, 2018) we have:

- [309 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [262 questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [99%-ish answer rate, which puts us at 21st overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 100% (with rounding, at least), and our rank site-wide at 1st for answering, and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

Comment: Link to previous version of this challenge: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/2017-trending-our-answered-percentage-ranking-to-1st

Comment: I have downvoted this because it promotes the addition of low-quality answers to difficult questions.

Comment: @phoog I disagree. It promotes addition of answers.. Upvotes/downvotes then reward/punish them, and that determines the quality, generally.

Comment: @MarkMayo that may be true in some cases, but in the past there have been some truly difficult questions that have attracted a a single answer during a campaign like this. I'm thinking of questions where the answer isn't readily available by searching a country's consular site, for example because of poor site design. The question would be easily answered by someone with experience with the matter, but no current user has that experience. The answer sounds plausible so it is upvoted by users who don't know better and do not have the benefit of comparing it with another answer.  Among ...

Comment: ...other things, this makes the question harder to find for a new user who might be able to answer it, because it will not appear in the unanswered questions list (a useful tool for new users looking to accrue reputation points).  That reduces the quality of the site.  For some questions, it really is best to sit unanswered until someone who knows the answer comes along.

Comment: @phoog Or it promotes the addition of difficult questions to other network sites ;)

Comment: This has been going on for a while. Is the pursuit of the goal still active? Does it still have to be [meta-tag:featured]? What's the target in time/percentile/amount?

Answer (score 8):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answer rate](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
| October 23rd, 2018   |  245    |  209      | 99%       | 15th |
| September 10th, 2018 |  151    |  134      | 100%      | 14th |
| September 6th, 2018  |  154    |  140      | 100%      | 13th |
| September 5th, 2018  |  150    |  137      | 100%      | 13th |
| September 1st, 2018  |  127    |  118      | 100%      | 12th | 
| August 31st, 2018    |  128    |  117      | 100%      | 12th | 
| August 27th, 2018    |  129    |  117      | 100%      | 13th | 
| August 23rd, 2018    |  131    |  118      | 100%      | 13th | 
| August 22nd, 2018    |  132    |  119      | 100%      | 12th | 
| August 21st, 2018    |  127    |  114      | 100%      | 13th | 
| August 20th, 2018    |  137    |  126      | 100%      | 13th | 
| August 18th, 2018    |  142    |  128      | 100%      | 12th | 
| August 17th, 2018    |  146    |  130      | 100%      | 12th | 
| August 15th, 2018    |  157    |  142      | 99%       | 13th | 
| August 13th, 2018    |  164    |  144      | 99%       | 13th | 
| August 12th, 2018    |  187    |  170      | 99%       | 13th | 
| August 11th, 2018    |  190    |  169      | 99%       | 13th | 
| August 10th, 2018    |  209    |  182      | 99%       | 14th | 
| August 7th, 2018     |  234    |  215      | 99%       | 15th | 
| August 6th, 2018     |  249    |  214      | 99%       | 16th | 
| August 3rd, 2018     |  251    |  223      | 99%       | 16th | 
| August 2nd, 2018     |  272    |  228      | 99%       | 18th | 
| August 1st, 2018     |  274    |  232      | 99%       | 18th | 
| July 31st, 2018      |  296    |  248      | 99%       | 19th | 
| July 30th, 2018      |  327    |  276      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 26th, 2018      |  336    |  301      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 25th, 2018      |  348    |  316      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 23rd, 2018      |  397    |  376      | 99%       | 21st | 
| July 21st, 2018      |  396    |  374      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 20th, 2018      |  396    |  373      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 19th, 2018      |  398    |  374      | 99%       | 21st | 
| July 17th, 2018      |  398    |  373      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 15th, 2018      |  406    |  374      | 99%       | 21st | 
| July 14th, 2018      |  402    |  370      | 99%       | 20th | 
| July 11th, 2018      |  408    |  380      | 99%       | 21st | 
| July 10th, 2018      |  401    |  379      | 99%       | 21st |
| July 9th, 2018       |  421    |  386      | 99%       | 21st |
| July 8th, 2018       |  439    |  403      | 99%       | 21st |
| July 7th, 2018       |  467    |  427      | 98%       | 21st |
| July 6th, 2018       |  475    |  437      | 98%       | 21st |
| July 4th, 2018       |  502    |  450      | 98%       | 25th |
| July 3rd, 2018       |  511    |  457      | 98%       | 24th |
| March 29th, 2018     |  313    |  302      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 28th, 2018     |  323    |  307      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 27th, 2018     |  316    |  301      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 26th, 2018     |  318    |  305      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 22nd, 2018     |  316    |  299      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 20th, 2018     |  311    |  295      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 19th, 2018     |  301    |  288      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 18th, 2018     |  298    |  285      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 16th, 2018     |  301    |  287      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 15th, 2018     |  306    |  294      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 14th, 2018     |  316    |  300      | 99%       | 22nd |
| March 8th, 2018      |  308    |  284      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 6th, 2018      |  308    |  280      | 99%       | 21st |
| March 5th, 2018      |  321    |  282      | 99%       | 21st |
| February 27th, 2018  |  298    |  262      | 99%       | 21st | 
| February 26th, 2018  |  301    |  253      | 99%       | 21st | 
| February 25th, 2018  |  305    |  257      | 99%       | 21st | 
| February 22nd, 2018  |  309    |  262      | 99%       | 21st | 
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
```